# Stack Exchange app achievements overlay layer disappear on screen rotation

Tags: bug, android-app

There's a strange bug in the app.

When a question is opened and then you tap on achievements, achievements are loaded fine, but as soon as the screen is rotated the achievement fragment breaks down and the question content in the background starts appearing.

I have reproduced the bug after clearing cache and data and recorded its video for the reference.

[image]

You can access the video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y-YevVlnaUOGJDdzNSam45Um8/view?usp=drivesdk)

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: ONEPLUS 3
- OS Version: 7.0 (15)